# Contact form 7 Attachment success but upload not working

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, contact-form-7

I looked round and couldn't find a solution so i thought I would ask a question. I have a contact form and am trying to get users to upload a picture and save it to the uploads directory in wp-content. This is what I have in the file attachment field:

```
[photo]

uploads/name.jpg
```

The attachment get's sent but I can't find any photo uploaded. Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Comment: You need to do custom code in your functions.php file because contact form 7 stores it temporarily...

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I ended up using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/.

It works well with contact forms 7. Just make sure your php is upto date.

Answer (score 0):

**How your uploaded files are managed**

After a user uploads a file through your contact form, Contact Form 7 checks to see if: 1.) Any PHP errors have occurred; 2.) the file type and file size are valid; and then, if the check turns out okay, Contact Form 7 moves the uploaded file to a temporary folder. At this point, Contact Form 7 attaches the file to the mail and sends it. After these procedures, Contact Form 7 then removes the file from the temporary folder.

The location of the temporary folder is wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads by default. It may differ if you have changed upload path setting from wp-content/uploads.